# Controller responsibility to support methods with association

Tags: api-design

We are designing an API with multiple controllers and having discussion on where should we put one of the functionality and which controller should take responsibility to hold that. Will try to explain our use case by taking the example of Flight, Schedules, and Pilots. (consider all are having dedicated Controller and Service)

Flight will have multiple Schedules and each schedule have pilots. We have a method in Schedule controller which is returning schedule details along with pilots. 
What if we need a method to get all the schedules of pilot. Does it makes sense to keep this in Pilot Controller and invoke ScheduleService from there? Are we deviating from principles?

Comment: It makes sense to me. What makes you think that's wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Laiv My question is more like taking an opinion on design and see any better approach

Comment: Note that, asking for opinions is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the REST API naming conventions ([site](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)), it depends on the primary object requested. For example, if you request a pilot along with his schedule, the URL might look like this:

```
/api/pilots/{id}/schedule
```

So using the `PilotController` for this makes sense. And from the `PilotController`, you can indeed perfectly call the `ScheduleService` to get the schedule of the pilot.

The same applies for the flights and schedules.

So I would say that you are on the right road. Reading the mentioned [site](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) might give you a good foundation for your intuïtive start.